# Basic UNIX configure/make/sudo make install question

Tags: macos, makefile, autoconf, automake

I have learned to compile my own source over the years but always left some of the process to "mystery". I'm running into a *bitch* of a time getting **ImageMagick** and its myriad dependencies to work correctly on a PowerPC Mac OS X Server.

In setting flags for `./compile` where does one typically uncover the various options (flags) that can be set and the descriptions of what each does?!?

For example, in the case of `libwmf` I'm using:

```
./configure --without-expat --with-xml --with-png=/usr/X11
```

...but not really knowing what each flag does. Now I'm having a **png** compatibility problem and want to find out why `--with-png=/usr/X11` flag is being specified in [install script](https://github.com/masterkain/ImageMagick-sl/blob/master/install_im.sh) I'm following...but can't find any documentation, etc. Any help?

Even a general response of how the UNIX Guru approaches this problem would be helpful.

Comment: Try `./configure --help`

Comment: A "Unix Guru" knows: When in doubt try `--help`.

Comment: If you really want to plunge into the muddy waters of the auto tools, there is a book on the subject (which I can't entirely recommend, but then I don't find the subject very compelling) - see http://sourceware.org/autobook.

Comment: i wasn't aware of `./configure --help`. thx! maybe post some answers instead of comments so this question can wrap up in a timely manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`./configure --help` will give you the list of options that a `configure` script supports.  To find out details about each option or the arguments you have to supply in particular cases, you will have to read the installation documentation of the particular package, if it has one.  There are certain conventions that you will pick up over time, but they are just conventions.  If you build a rather complicated package such as ImageMagick that pulls in dozens of library dependencies, and you use a less-than-common platform such as Mac with hand-compiled stuff, you might really have to dig deep and hard in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac, `/usr/X11/lib` contains a lot of libraries, including `libpng.dylib` and `libpng.3.44.0.dylib` in particular.  Do you have those libraries?  If not, you need to get X11 installed onto your Mac, and things are likely to go more smoothly.

---

#### MacOS X for Intel

I've downloaded [ImageMagick 6.6.9-9](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) and configured, built and checked (but not installed) it with minimal issues.  I have XCode 4 on my machine - and the only special option I used with `./configure` was:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc ./configure
```

to ensure it picked up the system-provided GCC (4.2.1), not my private version of GCC 4.6.0.  (A configuration test failed - for the `sizeof(off_t)` - because of a library issue.  Using the system C compiler avoided that problem.)  The ImageMagick configuration printed out:

```
ImageMagick is configured as follows. Please verify that this configuration
matches your expectations.

Host system type: x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0
Build system type: x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0

                  Option                        Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shared libraries  --enable-shared=yes       yes
Static libraries  --enable-static=yes       yes
Module support    --with-modules=no     no
GNU ld            --with-gnu-ld=no      no
Quantum depth     --with-quantum-depth=16   16
High Dynamic Range Imagery
                  --enable-hdri=no      no

Delegate Configuration:
BZLIB             --with-bzlib=yes      yes
Autotrace         --with-autotrace=no       no
Dejavu fonts      --with-dejavu-font-dir=default    none
DJVU              --with-djvu=yes       no
DPS               --with-dps=yes        no
FFTW              --with-fftw=yes       no
FlashPIX          --with-fpx=yes        no
FontConfig        --with-fontconfig=yes     no
FreeType          --with-freetype=yes       yes
GhostPCL          None              pcl6 (unknown)
GhostXPS          None              gxps (unknown)
Ghostscript       None              gs (unknown)
Ghostscript fonts --with-gs-font-dir=default    none
Ghostscript lib   --with-gslib=no       no
Graphviz          --with-gvc=yes        no
JBIG              --with-jbig=yes       no
JPEG v1           --with-jpeg=yes       no (failed tests)
JPEG-2000         --with-jp2=yes        no
LCMS v1           --with-lcms=yes       no
LCMS v2           --with-lcms2=yes      no
LQR               --with-lqr=yes        no
LZMA              --with-lzma=yes       no
Magick++          --with-magick-plus-plus=yes   yes
OpenEXR           --with-openexr=yes        no
PERL              --with-perl=no        no
PNG               --with-png=yes        yes
RSVG              --with-rsvg=yes       no
TIFF              --with-tiff=yes       no
WEBP              --with-webp=yes       no
Windows fonts     --with-windows-font-dir=  none
WMF               --with-wmf=yes        no
X11               --with-x=         yes
XML               --with-xml=yes        yes
ZLIB              --with-zlib=yes       yes

X11 Configuration:
      X_CFLAGS        = 
      X_PRE_LIBS      = -lSM -lICE
      X_LIBS          = -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib
      X_EXTRA_LIBS    = 

Options used to compile and link:
  PREFIX          = /usr/local
  EXEC-PREFIX     = /usr/local
  VERSION         = 6.6.9
  CC              = /usr/bin/gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu99
  CFLAGS          = -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
  CPPFLAGS        = -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick
  PCFLAGS         = -fopenmp
  DEFS            = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
  LDFLAGS         = -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib
  MAGICK_LDFLAGS  = -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/X11/lib -R/usr/X11/lib
  LIBS            = -lMagickCore -lfreetype -lpng -lXext -lXt -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lbz2 -lxml2 -lz -lm -lgomp -lclparser -Wl,-framework,OpenCL -L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries -lm -lpthread 
  CXX             = g++
  CXXFLAGS        = -g -O2 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread
  FEATURES        = OpenMP
```

Some of the tests failed - I expect that was because I was not actually running an X11 server on the machine at the time.  I'm not immediately going to investigate - you are running into problems at a much earlier stage.

---

#### MacOS X for PowerPC

As you can see, this is for Snow Leopard (10.6.7) on Intel x86/64.  If you are running with Leopard (10.5.x) on PowerPC, you probably have an older XCode and libraries etc, but it would be surprising if the configuration process does not work if you have the XCode on the machine - and X11 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your question about the flags in the invocation:

```
./configure --without-expat --with-xml --with-png=/usr/X11
```

In general, you cannot be certain what each flag does because the
maintainer of the package is completely free to have the flags do whatever
they want.  There are certain conventions, but many are not well
understood by the package maintainers so you cannot fully rely on them.
Generally, the --with and --without are simply used to determine
what features to compile in.  For example, if you do not have libexpat
installed, you can set --without-expat to complete the build which would otherwise fail.
One would suspect that the default for the package is to attempt
to build with certain features that require libexpat, and the
configury will fail if libexpat is not present, so you set
--without-expat to turn off those features.

The --with-png option with an argument is, IMO, a completely
untrustworthy kludge.  I've never seen a package where it 
actually works.  Typically, all the configure script does
is take your /usr/X11 argument and add it (with "-L"
prepended) to LDFLAGS.  The idea is that this will cause
the linker to use /usr/X11/libpng.so and not some other
version of libpng, but the simple fact is that if you
have libpng somewhere else on your system and that other
location is in your LDFLAGS, it will be used.  In other
words, if you have /usr/lib/foo.so and /usr/lib/bar.so
and /usr/other/lib/foo.so and /usr/other/lib/bar.so,
there is simply no way to use /usr/lib/foo.so and /usr/lib/other/bar.so
short of deleting one of the libraries.  Rather than specifying
a path as an argument to --with-png, you are probably better
off doing "--with-png   LDFLAGS='-L/path -L/path2'", or just
ensure that your system is built so that the desired paths are 
searched by the linker.  (eg, specify the paths in /etc/ld.so.conf
or in /etc/ld.so.conf.d)